# Variable declaration from the value of a different variable

Tags: theory

This isn't really specific to one language, it's just something I'm very confused about. I was wondering if you can declare a variable using the value from a different variable.
ex:

```
 int a = 2;
 int ba = 3;
 //except instead of ba its b with the value of a so it would be b2=3;
```

I feel like I've done this before, but I can't for the life of me remember how it was done, or if I had ever done it in the first place.
I apologize if this isn't in the correct category, I can't make my own, and I don't really know what would be a better place for it.

Comment: Just to clarify... In your example is b = 1?

Comment: No, ba would be equal to three. What I'm asking about is if there are ways to make a variable name from the value of a seperate variable. so it wouldn't be ba = 3; it would be b(the value of a) = 3; or b2 = 3;

Comment: this might not be exactly what you're looking for, but consider using a 'map' of some sort.  For example, something like `b = new Object(); b[a] = 3;`

Comment: I haven't learned what maps are but I will certainly look into them. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, exec() accepts and executes strings that contain valid Python expressions. You should try this

```
>>> a = 2 
>>> exec('b' + str(a) + ' = ' + str(3))
>>> b2
```

The output will be 3

```
3
```